# How to model many-to-many relationships in ABAP Programming Model for Fiori?

Tags: abap, sap-fiori, cds

How to achieve many-to-many relationships using CDS/BOPF and associations?

For example, consider you have tables for Movies and Genres, where we want to assign genres to movies.

```
define table zmv_movies {
  key client   : abap.clnt not null;
  key id       : snwd_node_key not null;
  name         : abap.string(0);
  release_date : abap.dats;
  plot         : abap.string(0);

}

define table zmv_genres {
  key client : abap.clnt not null;
  key id     : snwd_node_key not null;
  name       : abap.string(0);

}
```

A good way to map many-to-many (n:m) relationships are junction tables, so I created:

```
define table zmv_moviesgenres {
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.screenCheck : false
  key movie_id           : snwd_node_key not null
    with foreign key [0..*,1] zmv_movies
      where client = syst.mandt
        and id = zmv_moviesgenres.movie_id;
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.screenCheck : false
  key genre_id           : snwd_node_key not null
    with foreign key [0..*,1] zmv_genres
      where client = syst.mandt
        and id = zmv_moviesgenres.genre_id;
}
```

How do I create transactional views that properly handle this?

### My attempts so far

I created a working example, but it fails on data consistency.

I changed `zmv_moviesgenres` to have its own primary key:

```
define table zmv_moviesgenres {
  key movie_genre_id : snwd_node_key not null;
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.screenCheck : false
  movie_id           : snwd_node_key not null
    with foreign key [0..*,1] zmv_movies
      where client = syst.mandt
        and id = zmv_moviesgenres.movie_id;
  @AbapCatalog.foreignKey.screenCheck : false
  genre_id           : snwd_node_key not null
    with foreign key [0..*,1] zmv_genres
      where client = syst.mandt
        and id = zmv_moviesgenres.genre_id;

}
```

Then I created some basic views, and then the transactional views:

MOVIES_TP:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZMVIMOVIESTP'
//@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Movies transactional view'

@VDM.viewType: #TRANSACTIONAL
@ObjectModel: {
  modelCategory: #BUSINESS_OBJECT,
  createEnabled: true,
  updateEnabled: true,
  deleteEnabled: true,

  compositionRoot: true,
  transactionalProcessingEnabled: true,
  writeActivePersistence: 'ZMV_MOVIES',

  draftEnabled: true,
  writeDraftPersistence: 'ZMVIDMOVIESTP',

  semanticKey: 'id'
}

define view ZMVI_Movies_TP
  as select from ZMVI_Movies
  association [0..*] to ZMVI_Movies_Genres_TP as _movies_genres on $projection.id = _movies_genres.movie_id
{
      @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
      key id,

      @ObjectModel.association.type: [ #TO_COMPOSITION_CHILD ]
      _movies_genres,
      name,
      release_date,
      plot
}
```

MOVIES_GENRES_TP:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZMVIMOVGENTP'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Movies Genres Transactional View'

@VDM.viewType: #TRANSACTIONAL

@ObjectModel: {
  createEnabled: true,
  updateEnabled: true,
  deleteEnabled: true,


  writeDraftPersistence: 'ZMVDMOVIESGENRES',
  writeActivePersistence: 'ZMV_MOVIESGENRES', 

  semanticKey: 'movie_genre_id',
  alternativeKey: [{id: 'movie_id'}]
} 

define view ZMVI_Movies_Genres_TP as select from ZMVI_Movies_Genres
    association [1..1] to ZMVI_Movies_TP as _movies on $projection.movie_id = _movies.id
    association [1..1] to ZMVI_GENRES_TP as _genres on $projection.genre_id = _genres.id
{

    key movie_genre_id,
    genre_id,
    movie_id,

    @ObjectModel.association.type: [ #TO_COMPOSITION_PARENT, #TO_COMPOSITION_ROOT ]
    _movies,
    _genres
}
```

GENRES_TP:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZMVIGENRESTP'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Genres transactional view'
@VDM.viewType: #TRANSACTIONAL
@ObjectModel: {
  modelCategory: #BUSINESS_OBJECT, 
  createEnabled: true,
  updateEnabled: true,
  deleteEnabled: true,

  compositionRoot: true,
  transactionalProcessingEnabled: true,
  writeActivePersistence: 'ZMV_GENRES',

  semanticKey: 'id',

  alternativeKey: [{element: ['_movies_genres']}]

}

define view ZMVI_GENRES_TP as select from ZMVI_Genres
  association [0..*] to ZMVI_Movies_Genres_TP as _movies_genres on $projection.id = _movies_genres.genre_id {
  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  key id,

  _movies_genres,
  name
}
```

This works. It connects movies to genres. But if I delete a genre, it does not validate if the genre is being used by a movie. I had to create a determination/validation for that to manually check.

Also, it allows repeated assignments (e.g. two lines of ["Star Wars | Sci-fi", "Star Wars | Sci-fi"])

I am using an S/4 1809 system, componentsSAP_ABA 75D, SAP_BASIS 753.

Is there any other way to do this?